# Custom list view not refreshing after changes

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, android-runonuithread

There are many questions on updating a custom list view, one common problems seems to be a reference issue with the ArrrayList as [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6483189/6859185) or a not calling update from the UI thread. Though I have not managed to fix my issue with those examples.

As far as I can tell, the Arraylist (`nameScoresList`) is being updated and the `getView` function in the adapter also appears to be called when `notifyDatasetChanged` is called. Looking at the logs in different locations in the code the Arraylist is changing with the new values.

However, the screen of the app remains with the original list view rendered and does not change with the altered values of `nameScoresList`.

Can anyone see the mistake I am making? Thanks

The code for my adapter is:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Activity activity;
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
        super();
        this.activity=activity;
        this.list=list;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_name_score, null);
            txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.score);
        }

        HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
        txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
        Log.d("CHECK_UPDATE", map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
        return convertView;
    }

//  Two previous attempts at an update function
//
//    public void refreshScores(float[] outputScores) {
//        int count = 0;
//        for(HashMap<String, String> entry : this.list) {
//            entry.put(SECOND_COLUMN, Float.toString(outputScores[count]));
//            count += 1;
//        }
//        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
//    }

//    public void refreshScores(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nameScoresList) {
//        list.clear();
//        list.addAll(nameScoresList);
//        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
//    }
}
```

These are the sections which I think are relevant from the main activity (I can add more if needed):

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> nameScoresList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public class SpeechActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Put data in nameScoresList;
    for (int i=0; i < speakerJson.entrySet().size(); i++){
      nameScoresList.add(new HashMap<String, String>());
    }
    int ID_number;
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : speakerJson.entrySet()) {
      speaker = entry.getKey();
      ID_number = entry.getValue().getAsInt();
      HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
      temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, speaker.replace("_", " "));
      temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, Float.toString(0));
      nameScoresList.set(ID_number - 1, temp);
    }

    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, nameScoresList);
    nameScoresLV.setAdapter(adapter);
    record();
}

  private void record() {
    // Get outputScores

    // Update Arraylist which ListView uses
    int count = 0;
    for (HashMap<String, String> entry : nameScoresList) {
      entry.put(SECOND_COLUMN, Float.toString(outputScores[count]));
      count += 1;
    }

    runOnUiThread(
        new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            // These are calls which correspond to the commented functions in ListViewAdapter class
            //adapter.refreshScores(outputScores);
            //adapter.refreshScores(nameScoresList);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You did not modify `nameScoresList` i.e its size is always Zero.

Comment: There's a commented line, "Put data in nameScoresList", which was a stand in for where I filled the list. I just wanted to make the code in the question a little shorter. My bad if that was not clear.

Comment: Override the `getCount()` in adapter and return the size of list .

Comment: I have logged the size of the list using getCount and it is 6. So the initialisation of the ArrayList doesn't seem to be the problem. (I updated the question to show how I initialise it)

Comment: If size is OK . Then first check the layout . And then Log Adapter. You will figure out the problemo . instead of using ` ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` Use a `List` of `POJO`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The original listview with names and scores shows on the screen, but the scores do not update as I obtain new ones. So I don't think the layout is the problem (you mean the xml file?). "Log adapter"? Do you mean, put log statments in the adapter to see whats going on?

Comment: Just seen the POJO part of your comment, I'll try that

Comment: Try move: txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name); txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.score); to outside the 'if'. Hope that helps!